# AsyncTask not working with okhttp post request

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, okhttp

The way the app behaves when I try to run it is black screen -> back to main activity.

Here's my code:

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    new NetworkTask().execute();
}

public void backToMain(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final String image = getExternalCacheDir() + "/image.jpeg";
        File file = new File(image);
        try {
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("images", "image.jpeg",
                            RequestBody.create(file, MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG))
                    .addFormDataPart("organs", "leaf")
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("insert url here")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String result = response.body().string();
            return result;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("error")) {
            textView.setText("error");
        } else {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain that the post request works just fine because I have tested it using:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

So, maybe the issue lies with the way I put it in AsyncTask.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated, and OkHttp has [its own way of doing asynchronous requests](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java).

Answer (score 0):

As Carl says, I put this line of code on doInBackground method. My problem has been solved.

```
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {   
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    //...
           }
```

Using AsyncTask is necessary in some cases such as sending a queue of images.